# An error is occur when i called Web browser....

Tags: windows-phone-7, webbrowser-control

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++) {
  ds = new Discription();

  PivotItem pivotItem = new PivotItem();
  pivotItem.Header = list.ElementAt(i).header.ToString();

  StackPanel sta = new StackPanel();
  WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();

  sta.Children.Add(wb);

  pivotItem.Content = sta;         
  Pivot_item1.Items.Add(pivotItem);
  wb.NavigateToString(list.ElementAt(i).Detail.ToString());
}
```

an error is occur when  calling  web browser control 
You cannot call WebBrowser methods until it is in the visual tree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Subscribe to the Loaded event of the Webbrowser control and move your navigation code to the loaded handler.

Replace the line

```
wb.NavigateToString(list.ElementAt(i).Detail.ToString());
```

with

```
var address = list.ElementAt(i).Detail.ToString();
wb.Loaded += (sender, e) => { wb.NavigateToString(address); }
```

Comment: if u have any example of Loaded event then please give me a link

Answer (score 0):

```
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++) {
        ds = new Discription();

          PivotItem pivotItem = new PivotItem();
            pivotItem.Header = list.ElementAt(i).header.ToString();

       Grid sta = new Grid();
         WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
         var address = list.ElementAt(i).Detail.ToString();
          wb.Loaded += (sender, e) => { wb.NavigateToString(address); };
       sta.Children.Add(wb);

         pivotItem.Content = sta;         
         Pivot_item1.Items.Add(pivotItem);
        wb.NavigateToString(list.ElementAt(i).Detail.ToString());
         }
```